Cache gets deleted and has to be rebuild
Magento 2.4.7-p3
My store deletes the cache (Varnish or any other 3rd party cache) multiple times a day by itself, it has to be rebuild afterwards. Any idea where and how to start looking for that type of problem? Since I do not know when it happens, I can not reproduce it by "clicking a button" unfortunately.
Ideas please :)
